# Getting three "346 cannot locate" for _ZTVN10__cxxabiv### symbols

Tags: android-ndk

The three symbols are:
_ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE
_ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
_ZTVN10__cxxabiv121__vmi_class_type_infoE

My project is a multi-platform C++ project with 53 source files and probably over 100 classes at this point, so I can't really post an example...plus if I knew what the problem was I wouldn't need to be here. Attempting to load the .so I compiled causes a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError with these three errors. (it really only shows one, so I dummied them out before posting this so I'd know all of the errors)

I'm currently compiling for android-9.

I used to work with NDK back in the 1.6 days, and I may have even experienced this problem once before, but I've been away from it for 3 years and thus I'm a bit rusty. I know that NDK has some odd quirks, such as failing to link if you have a static non-pointer instance of a class anywhere. (in old NDK versions this would fail at runtime with an undescriptive __dso_handle error) I've double checked all my code to ensure that no static code is executed upon library load, so that's not a concern.

That said, I'm at a loss at this point. Web searches reveal that other platforms have issues when compiling CPP files with GCC instead of G++, so I changed that...no improvement. Another site indicates that it's vtable related but has no info that I really know how to use. I can't really isolate which classes are causing this issue since so many of the classes rely on each other.

The only thing I can do is ask here if anyone else has had this issue and what general coding practices cause it?

EDIT: might as well include the cflags, lflags, and programs used:

- **cflags**: -c -DPLATFORM_ANDROID -DANDROID -march=armv5te -std=c99 -mtune=xscale -g -O0 -msoft-float -mthumb-interwork -fpic -ffunction-sections -fno-unwind-tables -fno-exceptions -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -w -Wno-psabi
- **lflags**: -lm -lc -lstdc++ -llog -lz -ldl -lGLESv1_CM -g -O0 -nostdlib -shared -olibsomename.so
- **gcc dir**: androidndkr10d\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
- **compiler**: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc (c) / arm-linux-androideabi-g++ (cpp)
- **linker**: arm-linux-androideabi-ld

Comment: That "vtable related" thing is wrong. I missed the absolute obvious that it is a part of RTTI. Using -fno-rtti seems to have gotten me past JNI_OnLoad() but I still have porting issues to work out and it might easily be a false fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out after posting this that it's RTTI related. Using -fno-rtti seems to be a legitimate fix with no apparent side effects after half a day or so of fixing up the port.